# Printing all possible sub array from define array

Tags: java

I am trying to print all possible sub array from define list. For doing that I am using below code

```
static void printSubArray(int arr[]) {
        int n = arr.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {
                for (int k = i; k <= j; k++) {
                    System.out.print(arr[k] + " ");
                }

                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
```

Tried above code some extend its working but not printing all the possible array.
For example please find below example:

Input::
int a[] = { 1, 2, 3 };

Output::

```
1 
1 2 
1 2 3 
2 
2 3 
3
```

As we can see in the output few of the subarray is missing like 1, 3.

Can some one please  help on this

Answer (score 0):

So a current number should be printed in its line, then it is excluded and all the following numbers are printed, with the current number passed on as a prefix to be included in further printings.

The number of sets is 2<sup>n</sup> - 1, where `n` is the length of the input array.

Thus, the following recursive solution can be developed:

```java
static void printSubArray(int ... arr) {
    printSubArray("", -1, arr);
}

static void printSubArray(String prefix, int ix, int ... arr) {
    for (int i = ix + 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(prefix + arr[i]);
        printSubArray(prefix + arr[i] + " ", i, arr);
    }
}
```

For the input `printSubArray(1, 2, 3)` it prints:

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 3
2
2 3
3
```

For the input `printSubArray(1, 2, 3, 4)` it prints:

```java
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 4
1 3
1 3 4
1 4
2
2 3
2 3 4
2 4
3
3 4
4
```